# For what value of $\alpha$, does this series converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I Have the next Series and i need to find for what value of $\alpha$ the series converge.

$\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_{n}}}{n^{\alpha}}$

Hipothesis: $\sum a_{n}$ converge, $a_{n}$ positive

So, waht i tried to use is the "Root Test" since i know that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_{n}} < 1$$ (Hypothesis from $\sum a_{n}$ converge).

Doing that  ends on the series converging for all $\alpha$. I sense there is something wrong. Any advice on how to work with this series. Why is neccesary the Hypothesis?

Comment: Yes! Forgot to add that, part of the hypothesis

Comment: $$\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^\alpha} \le (\sum \frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}})^{1/2}(\sum a_n)^{1/2}$$ so $\alpha > .5$ works.

Comment: Taking $a_n=\frac 1{n^{1+\epsilon}}$ shows that you can't have $\alpha <.5$  ...  That just leaves $\alpha =.5$ to sort out.

Comment: $a_n = \frac{1}{n\log^2 n}$ rules out $\alpha = .5$ (and less than .5).

Comment: @mathworker21 Would you explain both of your comments?. I don't follow. What is wrong with the reasoning that i used (Root Test). Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{My comments}$:

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality yields $$\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^\alpha} \le (\sum \frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}})^{1/2}(\sum a_n)^{1/2},$$ so if $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$, the series converges. Now consider $a_n = \frac{1}{n\log^2n}$. Indeed, $\sum a_n < \infty$ (by integral test for example), but $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^\alpha} = \sum \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}+\alpha}\log n}$ so if $\alpha \le \frac{1}{2}$, this series diverges.

.

$\textbf{Root test}$:

Note $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^\alpha})^{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(a_n)^{1/2n}}{n^{\alpha/n}} = 1,$$ so the root test doesn't tell us anything (for any $\alpha$).

Comment: i though since  $\sum a_{n}$ converge (From the hypothesis of the problem) that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} a_{n} < 1$$ (Root test), is this wrong to asume? And then $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(a_n)^{1/2n}}{n^{\alpha/n}} <1,$$ because the numerator would be < 1. At this point i know is wrong but i do not know why. Thanks.

Comment: Antoher thing, why do you consider $a_n = \frac{1}{n\log^2n}$, being a particular sequence.?

Comment: I have read your answer and i understand the use of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but i dont know why you consider that particular sequence, and why you can do it, it never occurred to me. Thanks

Comment: @Karl both the numerator and denominator will converge to $1$. A general result is that if a sequence $(x_n)_n$ doesn't grow too quickly, then $x_n^{1/n} \to 1$. Neither the sequences $\sqrt{a_n}$ nor $n^\alpha$ grow too quickly. To make this rigorous, one could take logarithms and use Lhopitals rule.

Comment: @Karl the motivation for choosing $a_n = \frac{1}{n\log^2 n}$ stems from the fact that $\sum \frac{1}{n\log^2 n}$ is summable while $\sum \frac{1}{n\log n}$ is not. And this fact is exactly what I use

Comment: So, could i use any other sequence $b_n$ if $\sum b_n < \ infinity$ to find out for what values of $\alpha$ my original series converge ? Does it makes sense what i'm saying ?

Comment: @Karl Well, it depends what the question is. Is the sequence $(a_n)_n$ fixed, or are we looking over all sequences $(a_n)_n$ and asking what $\alpha$ works for them all?

Comment: What i meant is, you chose that particular $(a_n)_n$, could have i chosed another one?, and what should i be searching in that sequence? You said that your motivation was that, that sequence is summable, but there are others, you chose a "random" sequence, where in my problem, the only hint is that $\sum a_n$ converge, but there an could be "anything"

Comment: I was trying to say that your initial question is unclear. Is the sequence $(a_n)_n$ fixed and you're asking which $\alpha$ work for that sequence? Or are you asking which $\alpha$ work for every sequence $(a_n)_n$? For the first question, the answer of course depends on $(a_n)_n$. For the second question (which is the question I answered), I chose that particular sequence $(a_n)_n$ because I knew it is "barely summable" and would thus solve the problem for us

Comment: Thanks, i edited my initial question, because the hypothesis was wrong, does not change the problem though. But maybe you can see that what i am assuming is that $\sqrt[n]{a_n} < 1$ when n tends to inifinity(thats from the root test, is that wrong? and then i used that